# Is this mapping between several columns and one Dictionary possible?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have the following DB Schema and a POCO class.

```
Table ClassA
[ID] int NOT NULL

Table DPV
[ClassName] nvarchar(max) NOT NULL
[ObjectID] int NOT NULL
[Name] nvarchar(max) NOT NULL
[Value] nvarchar(max) NULL
```

```
public class ClassA
{
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public Dictionary<string, string> AssociatedDPVs { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to map the above schema to the POCO so that when I load a `ClassA` from the DB context, `ClassA.AssociatedDPVs` will be populated similar to this:

```
DPVs.Where(d => d.ClassName == "ClassA" && d.ObjectID == this.ID)
    .ToDictionary(d => d.Name, d => d.Value)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to map it. EF is only able to map database relations but you can probably achieve it through workaround (untested - just an idea).

Pseudocode:

```
var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext;
objectContext.ObjectMaterialized += (sender, e) => {
    var context = sender as ObjectContext; 
    var entity = e.Entity as ClassA;
    if (entity != null) {
       entity.AssociatedDPVs = context.CreateObjectSet<DPV>()
                                      .Where(d => d.ClassName == "ClassA" && d.ObjectID == entity.ID)
                                      .ToDictionary(d => d.Name, d => d.Value);
    }
};
```

This should hopefully solve the problem for retrieving DPVs. If you also need to persist DPVs you will have to override `SaveChanges` on `DbContext` and tell EF which DPVs should be added, modified or deleted (so you must have this information and just `Name` and `Value` will not tell it to you).

Comment: insided the event handler, ObjectContext variable doesn't have the DPVs property. is there a way to get DbContext back from ObjectContext?

Comment: Yes it doesn't have `DPVs` property. My fault, I've updated the answer.

Comment: One more question - It seems that ObjectMaterialized event is raised for each ClassA entity. So when I am fetching N ClassAs, does the query to get DPV get executed N times as well?

Comment: Yes it will call the event for every fetched entity and it will result in N queries but you will not make it better if you want to have this logic wrapped inside EF. You will need to use two separate queries - one for ClassAs and second for all needed DPVs and manually fill `AssociatedDPVs` on classA entities from the result of the second query.